# Convolution of uniform and normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, uniform-distribution

Consider a random variable U that has a uniform distribution on (0,1) and a random variable $X$
that has a standard normal distribution. Assume that $U$ and $X$ are independent. Determine an expression for the probability density function of the random variable $Z=U+X$ in terms of the cumulative distribution function of $X$.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365601/convolution-for-uniform-distribution-and-standard-normal-distribution) solves the problem by expanding the convolution as $$f_Z(z) = \int_0^1 f_U(u) f_X(z-u) \mathrm{d}u.$$

I can see the bounds of the integral are 'less messy' when expanding as above; however, why is expanding the convolution as follows invalid? $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_U(z-x) \mathrm{d}x.$$ $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$

In general, can some convolution problems only be solved by expanding the functions one way as a result of the constraints of the input bounds?

Comment: $f_U(z-x)$ is not always $1$. It takes two values: $0$ and $1$. You have to see when it is equal to $1$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So $f_Z(z)$ is only non-zero when $z-x >= 0$ and $z-x<=1$. This gives the lower bound of the integral to be $x=z-1$ and upper bound to be $x=z$. This gives $$f_Z(z) = \int_{x=z-1}^zf_X(x) dx$$
$$f_Z(z) = [\Phi(x)]_{z-1}^z $$Is this correct?